# Can't Access to my Amazon Instance with public Ip

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I have a new amazon instance EC2, and I want to build a Web Server so I did :

1. Install apache2
2. Install libapache2-mod-php5
3. a2enmod rewrite
4. Add a Http rule in the default group to allow all IP
5. add Directory AllowOverride All in /etc/apache2/sites-availables/ default-conf

But when I want to check if apache is running by typing the public ip of the instance in my browser, I dont have the basic index.html "it's  works". I got nothing.

What does i missed ?

Thanks you.

Comment: What error message do you get ?

Comment: I dont have error, just "Innacessible website"

Comment: Can you provide the output of `netstat -tunalp | grep :80`

Comment: I go this when i type this command : 
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -

Comment: run this command using root user. And looking at your output, port 80 is LISTENING on ipv6 not ipv4. Check your network configuration.

Comment: When i using root : tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1117/apache2. How can i change to listenning on ipv4 ?

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: Yep, it's works :) Thanks you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

It was a problem with the firewall.

The security group that I changed was not the one that was linked with my Instance

My bad.

Answer (score 3):

If apache is running fine, then it might be the firewall.

In the AWS console, make sure you have unblocked port 80 in the "Security Groups" under "Network & Security".

Comment: Yep, i added the rule to allow the port 80,but it still not working

Answer (score 1):

do you know if the apache is running?  you can check with:

```
ps aux |grep -i 'http\|apache'
```

if it has not started, you can try:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

Comment: Thank you for u response, Apache is running when i type this command :). But i still cant access to it